# REALbasic speak equivalent for Linux

Tags: linux, text-to-speech, realbasic

I have a number of small REAL Studio apps that use the **Speak** keyword on Windows and Mac to output single words or short phrases.

Can anyone recommend a way of emulating this on Linux versions of the app, either with a shell command or a Soft declare?

These apps are for family use only so I can install free software on Ubuntu if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) is a TTS application available on many Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

Real Studio 2012 Release 2 added support for the Speak command on Linux.

http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Speak